# Do I need to toivel Britta water pitcher?

Tags: tevilas-keilim-dipping, keilim

Does a Britta water filtering pitcher need toiveling?

Comment: Why would you think they need to be toiveled?Aren't they made of plastic?

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) Devorah, Please consider [registering](//judaism.stackexchange.com/users/signup-unregistered) your account, to [enable](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44557/why-should-i-register-my-account) more site features, including voting.

Hope to see you around!

Comment: @sam Might be a shailo whether you have to toivel the actual filter, no?

Comment: @sam there are some opinions that require plastic being toiveled.

Comment: This strikes me as a practical question that should be addressed to a rabbi. Unless it's reworded to be either 1) some uniqueness of brita pitchers and the discussion regarding that or 2) the discussion regarding wether plastic needs tevillah  or something else.

Answer (score 1):

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brita) explains how the Britta pitchers are made:

> BRITA products include water jugs, kettles and tap attachments, all of
>   which use silver-impregnated activated carbon and ion-exchange resin
>   disposable filters as their primary filtering mechanism. The
>   activated carbon used in BRITA filters is produced from coconut
>   shells. The company manufactures its pitchers from styrene methyl
>   methacrylate copolymer.

Coconut shells would not require tevilla.

As for the pitcher itself which is, essentially, plastic, [Kof-K](https://www.kof-k.org/articles/040108090413w-3%20tevilas%20keilim.pdf) says:

> The consensus of the majority of the poskim is that utensils made from
>   plastic do not require a tevilah prior to use. An example of this is
>   Tupperware utensils. There are some poskim who say that fortunate is
>   the one who is careful to tovel plastic. The same holds true for
>   utensils made from rubber.

Refer to the footnotes in each article for additional info and details.

Comment: Might be worth mentioning that, if you toivel plastic alone, it should be without a bracha

Comment: @mbloch It's a good point. But, I also suggested reading the footnotes in the article. I believe, one of them mentions this.